# MonoTouch.Dialog: EntryElement's background color

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

How is the **background color** of a `EntryElement` changed in `MonoTouch.Dialog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class PaperEntryElement: EntryElement
{
    public PaperEntryElement(string caption, string placeholder, string value)
        : base(caption,placeholder,value)
    {
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell= base.GetCell(tv);
        cell.BackgroundColor = 
           UIColor.FromPatternImage(MediaProvider
                                       .GetImage(ImageGeneral.paper_tile));
        return cell;
    }
}
```